# Find the general solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y+x^2-y-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm confused on how to separate this equation.  Can someone help me get started or provide some hints?

Find the general solution of the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2y+x^2-y-1$

Comment: Try to factor the right side and separate the variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get you started: Factoring the right side, we find that

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x^2 y + x^2 - (y + 1) = (y + 1)(x^2 - 1)$$

Upon rearrangement,

$$\frac{dy}{y + 1} = (x^2 - 1) dx$$

Comment: I can get it into this form: $x^2(y+1)-(y+1)$ but I don't know how you got the rest.

Comment: @inquisitor Factor out a common term.

Comment: I did what you said and I get this: $\frac{dy}{y+1}=x^2-(y+1)dx$ and then I distributed the $-1$ and get $\frac{dy}{y+1}=(x^2-y-1)dx$ and so lastly I just added $y$ to the other side with and got $y+\frac{dy}{y+1}=(x^2-1)dx$

Comment: @inquisitor Look for a common term of $y + 1$ on the right hand side, and factor it out.

Comment: Wow.. I 'see' it now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can factor out the $x^2$ so your equation looks like,

$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = x^2(y+1)-y-1$

The rest shouldn't be too bad.

Answer (score 1):

After separating the variables, integrate on both sides.
$\log(y+1)=(x^3)-x+c$ 
Is the solution of given differential equation